# Unable to run grails test-app :cucumber

Tags: testing, grails, cucumber

So I've looked through other peoples problems but they dont match what I'm seeing so thought I'd post it up to see if anyone else has had this issue and has a suggested solution

Im running a grails app in 2.3.5 and have cucumber 1.2.0

I've set up a really basic feature file in the functional folder that reads as follows: -

```
Feature:
  As a user
  If I enter the incorrect password I need a warning message
  So I know i did something wrong


Scenario:
  Given I enter the wrong login credentials
  When I click sign in
  Then Display a login error
```

Now I know this shouldn't work as yet but Im going one step at a time to see the process as Im new to cucumber and grails.

The app runs fine if I use the command

`grails run-app -Dgrails.server.port.http=8090`

If I then try running the cucumber test via

`grails test-app :cucumber` (with or without the port specification above) I get the following explosion...

```
Configuring Shiro ...

Shiro Configured
| Error 2017-03-15 08:28:35,222 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: null
Message: null
    Line | Method
->> 2076 | contains       in java.lang.String
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    207 | canAutoMigrate in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils
|     43 | autoRun . . .  in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner
|     87 | doCall         in DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin$_closure2
|    262 | run . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker      in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run            in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2017-03-15 08:28:35,247 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing Grails: null
Message: null
    Line | Method
->> 2076 | contains       in java.lang.String
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    207 | canAutoMigrate in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils
|     43 | autoRun . . .  in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner
|     87 | doCall         in DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin$_closure2
|    262 | run . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker      in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run            in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2017-03-15 08:28:35,251 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [localhost].[/test]  - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
Message: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NullPointerException: null
->> 2076 | contains  in java.lang.String
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    207 | canAutoMigrate in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils
|     43 | autoRun . in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner
|     87 | doCall    in DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin$_closure2
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2017-03-15 08:28:35,271 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Error listenerStart
| Error 2017-03-15 08:28:35,280 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Context [/myProject] startup failed due to previous errors
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/myProject
| Server stopped
| Error Fatal error running tests: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered? (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in /Users/me/Projects/myProject/target/test-reports
| Error Error executing script TestApp: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered? (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I have 0 idea what any of this means and googling any of it with a grails/cucumber context doesnt seem to really bring anything of sense back, any suggestions or questions welcome!

This is the content of my bootstrap.groovy file if that makes things any clearer, intellij doesn't register anything in here as broken just a few variables not being used...

```
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.Sha256Hash
import uk.co.test.*

import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class BootStrap {

    def queueService

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def adminRole = new ShiroRole(name: "admin")
        adminRole.addToPermissions("admin:*:*")
        adminRole.save()

        def userRole = new ShiroRole(name: "user")
        userRole.addToPermissions("application:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("assertion:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("auth:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("displayResult:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("event:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("executor:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("folderNode:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("form:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("interaction:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("manualTest:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("object:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("objectType:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("page:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("project:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("queue:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("release:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("result:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("test:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("testSet:*:*")
        userRole.addToPermissions("user:*:*")
        userRole.save()

        def adminUser = new ShiroUser(username: "admin", passwordHash: new Sha256Hash("test").toHex())
        adminUser.addToRoles(adminRole)
        adminUser.addToRoles(userRole)
        adminUser.save()

        def nonAdminUser = new ShiroUser(username: "user", passwordHash: new Sha256Hash("test").toHex())
        nonAdminUser.addToRoles(userRole)
        nonAdminUser.save()

        if (Interaction.list().size() == 0) {
            def interaction = new Interaction('click')
            interaction.save(failOnError: true)

            interaction = new Interaction(name: 'check text', alias: 'checkText')
            interaction.save(failOnError: true)

            interaction = new Interaction(name: 'get attribute', alias: 'getAttribute')
            interaction.save(failOnError: true)

            interaction = new Interaction(name: 'enter text', alias: 'type')
            interaction.save(failOnError: true)

            interaction = new Interaction('select radio button')
            interaction.save(failOnError: true)

            interaction = new Interaction('select')
            interaction.save(failOnError: true)

            interaction = new Interaction('hover')
            interaction.save(failOnError: true)
        }

        if (ObjectType.findAll().size() == 0) {
            def firstType = new ObjectType(type: "button", typeSysCode: "BUTTON")
            firstType.save()
            def secondType = new ObjectType(type: "link", typeSysCode: "LINK")
            secondType.save()
            def thirdType = new ObjectType(type: "label", typeSysCode: "LABEL")
            thirdType.save()
            def fourthType = new ObjectType(type: "textbox", typeSysCode: "TEXTBOX")
            fourthType.save()
        }

        if (Queue.list().size() == 0) {
            def manualQueue = new Queue(name: "manual",
                    allowedTestTypes: [TestTypes.MANUAL.getValue()]
            )
            manualQueue.save(failOnError: true)
        }

        def sd =  Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
        sd.scheduleAtFixedRate(new QueueRunnable(), 10, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        environments {
            development {
                def firstRelease
                def secondRelease
                if (Release.findAll().size() == 0) {
                    def firstProject
                    def secondProject
                    if (Project.findAll().size() == 0) {
                        firstProject = new Project(name: "d2c application")
                        firstProject.save(failOnError: true)
                        secondProject = new Project(name: "b2b application")
                        secondProject.save(failOnError: true)
                    } else {
                        firstProject = Project.findByName("d2c application")
                        secondProject = Project.findByName("b2b application")
                    }

                    if (Release.findAll().size() == 0) {
                        firstRelease = new Release(name: "d2c 1", project: firstProject)
                        firstRelease.save()
                        secondRelease = new Release(name: "d2c 2", parentRelease: Release.findByNameAndProject('d2c 1', firstProject), project: firstProject)
                        secondRelease.save()

                        def thirdRelease = new Release(name: "b2b 1", project: secondProject)
                        thirdRelease.save()
                        def fourthRelease = new Release(name: "b2b 2", parentRelease: Release.findByNameAndProject('b2b 1', secondProject), project: secondProject)
                        fourthRelease.save()

                    }
                } else {
                    firstRelease = Release.get(1)
                    secondRelease = Release.get(2)
                }

                if (Object.findAll().size() == 0 && Page.findAll().size() == 0) {
                    def firstObject = new Object(name: "BBC welcome text",
                            idType: "css",
                            locatorValue: "h2.hp-banner__text",
                            type: ObjectType.get(2),
                            release: firstRelease,
                            objectVersion: 1,
                            objectNumber: 1,
                            interaction: Interaction.findByName('check text')
                    )
                    firstObject.save(failOnError: true)

                    def secondObject = new Object(name: "BBC news link",
                            idType: "css",
                            locatorValue: "li.orb-nav-news a",
                            type: ObjectType.get(1),
                            release: firstRelease,
                            objectVersion: 1,
                            objectNumber: 2,
                            interaction: Interaction.findByName('click')
                    )
                    secondObject.save(failOnError: true)

                    def thirdObject = new Object(name: "BBC news business link",
                            idType: "id",
                            locatorValue: "linky",
                            type: ObjectType.get(2),
                            release: firstRelease,
                            objectVersion: 1,
                            objectNumber: 3,
                            interaction: Interaction.findByName('click')
                    )
                    thirdObject.save(failOnError: true)

                    def firstPage = new Page(name: "BBC home",
                            pageNumber: 1,
                            pageVersion: 1,
                            release: firstRelease
                    )
                    firstPage.save(failOnError: true)

                    def secondPage = new Page(name: "BBC news",
                            pageNumber: 2,
                            pageVersion: 1,
                            release: firstRelease
                    )
                    secondPage.save(failOnError: true)

                    def firstPageObject = new PageObject(object: firstObject,
                            objectNumber: firstObject.objectNumber,
                            page: firstPage,
                            behaviour: "interact",
                            value: "Welcome to the BBC"
                    )
                    firstPageObject.save(failOnError: true)

                    def secondPageObject = new PageObject(object: secondObject,
                            objectNumber: secondObject.objectNumber,
                            page: firstPage,
                            behaviour: "interact"
                    )
                    secondPageObject.save(failOnError: true)

                    def thirdPageObject = new PageObject(object: thirdObject,
                            objectNumber: thirdObject.objectNumber,
                            page: secondPage,
                            behaviour: "interact"
                    )
                    thirdPageObject.save(failOnError: true)

                    firstPage.objects = [firstPageObject, secondPageObject]
                    firstPage.save(failOnError: true)
                    secondPage.objects = [thirdPageObject]
                    secondPage.save(failOnError: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add contents of `Bootstrap.groovy`? From the error it looks like the database migration grails plugin is throwing a NPE `contains  in java.lang.String` . Precisely it fails [at this line in the plugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/blob/1.x/src/groovy/grails/plugin/databasemigration/MigrationUtils.groovy#L187). Make sure database migration plugin is configured correctly. You can refer [**docs**](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/1.4.0/guide/configuration.html) to know about configuring dbmigration grails plugin.

Comment: Added, although the file itself doesn't show any errors when I open it other than a few variables that aren't being used.  Ill check the plugin to see if anything is wrong there, although the bootstrapping seems to work fine when running in dev mode :/